# How to convert Visual Foxpro database into SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foxpro, visual-foxpro

One of my clients has a Foxpro database (`.DBF` file). I need to convert it into a SQL Server 2008 database.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Kindly give me solution.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You may want to look at setting up a linked server. some info here http://serverfault.com/questions/361226/how-to-successfully-connect-to-foxpro-database-files-using-mssql-linked-server-f  and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: Should be pretty easy with the [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) - just open the `.dbf` file, transfer the data over into a SQL Server database table - done!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1.Create **ODBC Data Source to DBF** file

[image]

2.Using **SQL Server Import Data Wizard** (right click to database in the SSMS)

[image]

3.Choose **Data provider for ODBC** as data source

[image]

4.Map and **import your data**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "Upsizing Wizard" from the Visual FoxPro program, it's located on Tools -> Wizards -> Upsizing Wizard.

If you try this keep on mind two things:

- You need add the DBFs to a Database Container (it's a safe procedure: create a new Database and ADD the tables). **BACKUP**, those file can't be used as a "Free table" anymore. Again, talking about data is secure thing.
- You may need this into a 32bit concern, AFAIK there is no 64 bits ODBC driver for DBFs o VFP Databases. And the Upsizing Wizard don't work for OLEDB.

See more about it in this KB article: [HOWTO: How to Use the Upsizing (SQL) Wizard in Visual FoxPro](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129847)

Edit:

I totally forgot the improved Upsizing Wizard in Visual FoxPro 9 SP2, it's way better: [(VFP) Upsizing Simplified](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0703052)

Edit2: This could help:  [How to use SQL Server 2005 Integration Services (SSIS) to import Visual FoxPro data into SQL Server.](http://www.craigbailey.net/vfp-importing-vfp-data-into-sql-server/)

Comment: How do you get access to FoxPro? I'm stuck with a database and no way to access FoxPro to open it....

Comment: @DouglasGaskell - Visual Studio Subscription has it, last time I was subscribed, about a year ago.