# Import Foxpro tables into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

We have 800 different `.dbf` files and these need to load into SQL Server with their file name as the new table name, so `file1.dbf` has to be loaded into SQL Server into table `file1`.

Like this, we need to load all 800 Foxpro tables into SQL Server. Does anyone have an idea for this, or a script? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819811 (using ODBC DSN) or https://serverfault.com/questions/361226 (using OLE DB)

Comment: If you have Visual FoxPro available, get the latest version of the Upsizing Wizard from www.vfpx.org and use that.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to the problem. One is to use the upsizing wizard that ships with VFP. I only tried the original version and it was not good at all. I didn't use it since then. You may try uploading a test database with a single table that has, say a million rows in it, just to see if using that would be feasible to use (a million rows shouldn't take more than a minute).

What I did was to create a "generator" that would create the SQL server tables in the mapping I wanted (ie: memo to varchar or varbinary MAX, char to varchar etc). Then using a C# based activex code I wrote, I load the tables - multiple tables at a time (other ways of loading the tables were extremely slow). Since then that code is used to create SQL server tables and\or transfer exiting customers' data to SQL server.

Yet another effective way would be, create a linked server to VFP using VFPOLEDB and then use OpenQuery to get tables' structure and data:

```
select * into [TableName] 
from OpenQuery(vfpserver, 'select * from TableName ...')
```

This one is fast too and allows you to use VFP specific functions inside the query, however resulting field types might not be as you like.

Comment: Be aware that VFP and Sql Server have different definitions for the precision on Numeric() data types. For example, if your vfp field is Numeric(4,1) and you select a record with a value of 100 in that field, Sql Server will be upset. [Here's](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/666244/field-size-bug-when-importing-from-visual-foxpro) a small discussion about it.

Comment: @Supersnake, I am aware of the situation and I don't understand why you sent that message to me. With my proposed way of generating SQL server tables and do the importing via C# activex there isn't such a problem. There isn't such a problem with OpenQuery either. Your warning didn't make sense to me. After all I wish that would be the only thing one needs to be aware when upsizing to SQL server.

Comment: my comment was towards future people who find this page. We recently used an OpenQuery statement in Sql Server Management Studio to get VFP data and this was the cause for the error we were getting.

Comment: @Supersnake, with OpenQuery you are allowed to use VFP specific functions as I said above. You could have used that to prevent the issue. OTOH using numeric data type in VFP has never been a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that is written in FoxPro 9.  You will probably need to modify a bit as I only handled 3 data types.  You will also have to look out for SQL reserved words as field names.

---

```
SET SAFETY OFF
CLOSE ALL
CLEAR ALL
CLEAR

SET DIRE TO "C:\temp"

** house keeping
RUN del *.fxp
RUN del *.CDX
RUN del *.bak
RUN del *.err
RUN del *.txt

oPrgDir = SYS(5)+SYS(2003) && Program Directory
oPath = "C:\temp\pathtodbfs"  && location of dbfs

CREATE TABLE dbfstruct (fldno N(7,0), fldnm c(16), fldtype c(20), fldlen N(5,0), fldpoint N(7,0)) && dbf structure table

STORE SQLSTRINGCONNECT("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdbf;UID=root;PWD=root; OPTION=3") TO oConn  && SQL connection

SET DIRE TO (m.oPath)
STORE ADIR(aFL, "*.dbf") TO iFL && getting list of dbfs
SET DIRE TO (m.oPrgDir)
FOR i = 1 TO iFL
    IF AT("dbfstruct.dbf", LOWER(aFL(i,1))) = 0 THEN
        USE oPath + "\" + aFL(i,1)
        LIST STRUCTURE TO FILE "struct.txt" && output dbf structure to text file"
        SET DIRE TO (m.oPrgDir)

        USE dbfstruct
        ZAP
        APPEND FROM "struct.txt" TYPE SDF
        DELETE FROM dbfstruct WHERE fldno = 0 && removing non esential text
        PACK
        CLEAR
        DELETE FILE "struct.txt"

        SET DIRE TO (m.oPrgDir)

        =SQLEXEC(oConn, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testdbf." + STRTRAN(LOWER(aFL(i,1)),".dbf", "")) && needed to remove tables already created when I was testing

        sSQL = "CREATE TABLE testdbf." + STRTRAN(LOWER(aFL(i,1)),".dbf", "") + " ("

        SELECT dbfstruct
        GOTO TOP
        DO WHILE NOT EOF()
            @1,1 SAY "CREATING QUERY:  " + aFL(i,1)
            sSQL = sSQL + ALLTRIM(LOWER(dbfstruct.fldnm)) + " "
            * You may have to add below depending on the field types of your DBFS
            DO CASE
            CASE ALLTRIM(dbfstruct.fldtype) == "Character"
                sSQL = sSQL + "VARCHAR(" + ALLTRIM(STR(dbfstruct.fldlen)) + "),"
            CASE ALLTRIM(dbfstruct.fldtype) == "Numeric" AND dbfstruct.fldpoint = 0
                sSQL = sSQL + "INT(" + ALLTRIM(STR(dbfstruct.fldlen)) + "),"
            CASE ALLTRIM(dbfstruct.fldtype) == "Numeric" AND dbfstruct.fldpoint > 0
                sSQL = sSQL + "DECIMAL(" + ALLTRIM(STR(dbfstruct.fldlen)) + "),"
            OTHERWISE
                =MESSAGEBOX("Unhandled Field Type: " + ALLTRIM(dbfstruct.fldtype) ,0,"ERROR")
                CANCEL
            ENDCASE
            SELECT dbfstruct
            SKIP
        ENDDO
        sSQL = SUBSTR(sSQL, 1, LEN(sSQL)-1) + ")"
        STORE SQLEXEC(oConn, sSQL) TO iSQL

        IF iSQL < 0 THEN
            CLEAR
            ?sSQL
            STORE FCREATE("sqlerror.txt") TO gnOut && SQL of query in case it errors
            =FPUTS(gnOut, sSQL)
            =FCLOSE(gnOut)
            =MESSAGEBOX("Error creating table on MySQL",0,"ERROR")
            CANCEL
        ENDIF

        CLOSE DATABASES
    ENDIF
ENDFOR

=SQLDISCONNECT(oConn)

SET DIRE TO (m.oPrgDir)

SET SAFETY ON
```